# How can I check if the email has been confirmed by the guest before sending the second email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-authentication

I use Laravel 5.8, and I would like to send two emails after registration.
I want the first email to go to the guest directly after registration and the second to the user after the guest has confirmed his email address. Below, this can be seen below in the function verify.

**Save method**

```php
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $validate = array(
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:255'],
        'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:255'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'max:20'],
        'land' => ['required', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:guests'],
        'user_id' => ['required', 'string', 'exists:users,id']
    );
    $this->validate($request, $validate);
    $token = $request['user_id'].Str::random(22);
    $guest = new Guest;
    $guest->name = $request['name'];
    $guest->surname = $request['surname'];
    $guest->phone = $request['phone'];
    $guest->land = $request['land'];
    $guest->email = $request['email'];
    $guest->user_id = $request['user_id'];
    $guest->email_token = $token;
    $guest->save();

    MailController::send($request['email'], $request['name'], $token);
    //if (email_verified === 1)
    MailController::user_send($request['user_id'], $guest);

    return view('guest-success');
}
```

**Verify method**

```php
public function verify($token = false)
{
    if ($token == false) $token = Cookie::get('token') ?? false;
    else Cookie::queue('token', $token, 60 * 24 * 365);
    if ($token === false) return view('no_tp');
    $guest = Guest::where('email_token', $token)->first();
    if ($guest === null) return view('no_tp');
    $guest->email_verified = 1;
    $guest->email_verified_at = time();
    $guest->save();
    $user = User::find($guest->user_id);
    Cookie::queue('TP', $user->user_id, 60 * 24 * 365);

    return view('public-profile', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your question is? You've posted code and said "this is what I want to do" but no explanation of what's not working, error messages, where exactly you need help, etc.

Comment: Move your after-verification email send to the `verify()` method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably misunderstood something there. When I install the after-verification email in the verify method, I get the error that `$request` is undefined.
how should I install this correctly?

Comment: thanks all for help! I find the answer in an other place! can be closed.